# Theorem 6.10 of Baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity, proof-writing, solution-verification

> **Theorem 6.10** Suppose $f$ is bounded on $[a, b]$, $f$ has only finitely many points of discontinuity on $[a, b]$, and $\alpha$ is continuous at every point at which $f$ is discontinuous. Then $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$.

> **Proof:** Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. Put $M = \sup \left\vert f(x) \right\vert$, let $E$ be the set of points at which $f$ is discontinuous. Since $E$ is finite and $\alpha$ is continuous at every point of $E$, we can cover $E$ by finitely many disjoint intervals $\left[ u_j, v_j \right] \subset [a, b]$ such that the sum of the corresponding differences $\alpha\left(v_j\right) - \alpha \left( u_j \right)$ is less than $\varepsilon$. Furthermore, we can place these intervals in such a way that every point of $E \cap (a, b)$ lies in the interior of some $\left[ u_j, v_j \right]$.
> Remove the segments $\left( u_j, v_j \right)$ from $[a, b]$. The remaining set $K$ is compact. Hence $f$ is uniformly continuous on $K$, and there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\left\vert f(s) - f(t) \right\vert < \varepsilon$ if $s \in K$, $t \in K$, $\left\vert s-t \right\vert < \delta$.
> Now form a partition $P = \left\{ x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n \right\}$ of $[a, b]$, as follows: Each $u_j$ occurs in $P$. Each $v_j$ occurs in $P$. No point of any segment $\left( u_j, v_j \right)$ occurs in $P$. If $x_{i-1}$ is not one of the $u_j$, then $\Delta x_i < \delta$.
> Note that $M_i - m_i \leq 2M$ for every $i$, and that $M_i - m_i \leq \varepsilon$ unless $x_{i-1}$ is one of the $u_j$. Hence, as in the proof of Theorem 6.8,
> $$ U(P, f, \alpha) - L(P, f, \alpha) \leq \left[ \alpha(b) - \alpha(a) \right] \varepsilon + 2M \varepsilon.$$
> Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, Theorem 6.6 shows that $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$.

I don’t “really” understand the proof. To be more specific

> (1)Since $E$ is finite and $\alpha$ is continuous at every point of $E$, we can cover $E$ by finitely many disjoint intervals $\left[ u_j, v_j \right] \subset [a, b]$ such that the sum of the corresponding differences $\alpha\left(v_j\right) - \alpha \left( u_j \right)$ is less than $\varepsilon$.

> (2)Furthermore, we can place these intervals in such a way that every point of $E \cap (a, b)$ lies in the interior of some $\left[ u_j, v_j \right]$.

> (3)If $x_{i-1}$ is not one of the $u_j$, then $\Delta x_i < \delta$.

> (4)Note that $M_i - m_i \leq 2M$ for every $i$.

> (5)Hence, as in the proof of Theorem 6.8,
> $ U(P, f, \alpha) - L(P, f, \alpha) \leq \left[ \alpha(b) - \alpha(a) \right] \varepsilon + 2M \varepsilon.$

Now I will try to address more explicitly what I’m not able to understand. I will sort of try to prove each sentences from above.

(1) let $\epsilon \gt 0$ given and $E=\{ d_1 ,d_2,....,d_{k}\}$; $k \in \Bbb{N}$. Since $\alpha$ is continuous at $d_{j}$, $\exists  \delta_{j} \gt 0$ s.t $|x-d_j| \lt \delta_{j} \Rightarrow |\alpha(x)-\alpha(d_j)| \lt \epsilon$. $x-\delta_j \lt d_j \lt \delta_j +x$, choose $u_j \in (x-\delta_j, d_j)$ & $v_j \in (d_j, \delta_j +x)$ such that $v_{j-1} \lt u_{j}$ & $v_j \lt u_{j+1}$ respectively. Thus, $\alpha(v_j) - \alpha(u_j) \lt \epsilon$ and each $[u_j , v_j]$ contains $d_j$ and $[u_m , v_m] \cap [u_n , v_n] = \phi $, $m \neq n$. In other words, $[u_j , v_j]$ are disjoint. $\{[u_j , v_j]|j \in J_{k}\}$ obviously cover $E$.

(2) I don’t satisfactorily understand that sentence.

(3) Is it one of the axiom of construction of partition $P$ of $[a,b]$?

(4) That inequality seems obvious but I can’t prove it formally. I won’t be surprise if it is a few liner proof.

(5) Just the way inequality is written. Perhaps we are using the same “technique” as in theorem 6.11. Which is, to divide the members of partition $P$ into two category: $i \in A$ if $x_{i-1} \neq u_j, \forall j$ and $i \in B$ if $x_{i-1}=u_{j}$, for some $j$. $M_i - m_i \leq \epsilon$ for $i \in A$, since $\Delta x_i \lt \delta$(**Proof:** $|s_i - t_i|\leq \Delta x_i \lt \delta \Rightarrow |f(s_i)-f(t_i)| \lt \epsilon \Rightarrow M_i - m_i \leq \epsilon$. But I’m not sure about this proof because $s_i, t_i \in K$ ). So, $ \sum_{i \in A} (M_i - m_i) \Delta \alpha_i \leq \epsilon (\alpha(b) - \alpha(a))$. what’s about $\sum_{i \in B} \Delta \alpha_i$?

Comment: What is $\alpha$ and what is $\mathscr{R}(\alpha)$?

Comment: @K.defaoite $\alpha$ is monotonically increasing function on $[a,b]$, and $\mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ is a space of Riemann Stieltjes integral with respect to $\alpha$.

Comment: It’s a standard notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1)(2)
Assume $E=\{t_1,...,t_n\}$. It is possible to choose $\delta'>0$ so that
$$\lvert\alpha(t)-\alpha(t_i)\rvert<\frac{\epsilon}{2n}\quad(i=1,2,...,n)$$
provided that $\lvert t-t_i\rvert<\delta'$, $t\in[a,b]$. Hence if $\lvert t-t_i\rvert<\delta'$ and $\lvert s-t_i\rvert<\delta'$,
$$\lvert \alpha(t)-\alpha(s)\rvert<\frac{\epsilon}{n}\mbox{.}$$
For $t\in E\cap(a,b)$, choose $u_j,v_j\in(a,b)$ with $t-\delta'<u_j<t<v_j<t+\delta'$. If $a\in E$, let $u_j=a$ and choose $v_j$ with $u_j=a<v_j<a+\delta'$. If $b\in E$, let $v_j=b$ and choose $u_j$ with $b-\delta'<u_j<b=v_j$. It follows that
$$\sum_j\lvert\alpha(u_j)-\alpha(v_j)\rvert<n\frac{\epsilon}{n}= \epsilon \mbox{.}$$

(3)
$P$ is constructed in such a way that the uniform continuity of $f$ can be applied.

(4)
By definition of $M$,
$$-M\leq f(x)\leq M\quad (a\leq x\leq b)\mbox{,}$$
so that
$$-M\leq m_i\leq M_i\leq M\mbox{,}$$
and hence $M_i-m_i\leq 2M$.

(5)
The contribution of the continuous part of $f$ to $U-L$ can be estimated as follows
$$\sum (M_i-m_i)\Delta\alpha_i\leq\epsilon\sum\Delta\alpha_i\leq\epsilon(\alpha(b)-\alpha(a))\mbox{,}$$
where the sum is taken over all $i$ such that $x_i$ is not one of the $u$'s.
The other part can be estimated as follows
$$\sum(M_i-m_i)\Delta\alpha_i\leq 2M\sum \Delta\alpha_i<2M\epsilon\mbox{.}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I’m extremely sorry for the late reply. I was busy. Anyway I think there is a typo, $ n \frac{\epsilon}{n}=n$. I must say your answer to (3) is excellent and concise, but it left out main crux of the proof. It is not “trivial” to show $M_i - m_i \leq \epsilon$, if $i \in A$ (at least when you are not drawing pictures and there are lots of things to keep track of, that makes the proof little bit challenging). I was worried that $s_i ,t_i \in [x_{i}, x_{i-1}]$ may also $s_i$ or $t_i$ $\in (u_j,v_j)$, which is not allowed.

Comment: Then I make a hypothesis $[x_{i}, x_{i-1}] \nsubseteq (u_j,v_j)$, since $x_j \notin (u_j,v_j), \forall j$. Then i think of possibility $x_{i-1} \lt u_{j-1} \lt v_{j-1} \lt x_{i}$. Which is not true by first and second axiom of construction of $P$. In other word, in the above possibility $x_{i-1}$ and $x_{i}$ can’t be consecutive points of the partition, $x_{i-1}$ should be $v_{j-1}$. Thus, $[x_{i}, x_{i-1}]$ is neither a subset of $(u_j,v_j)$ nor it contain any point of $(u_j,v_j)$. Hence $[x_{i}, x_{i-1}] \subseteq K$. Now rest of the proof is straightforward.

Comment: (First line of previous comment)*$x_k \notin (u_j, v_j), \forall j$, for $0 \leq k \leq n$. Here $n$ has nothing to do with no. of discontinuity points of $f$.

Comment: Finally, $\sum_{i \in B} \Delta \alpha_i \lt \epsilon$ follows from the proof of $(1)(2)$. $\sum_{i \in B} \Delta \alpha_i = \sum_{i \in B} \alpha(x_i) - \alpha(u_j)$, for some j. Then $x_i$ must be equal to $v_j$, else it will contradict our axiom of construction of $P$. Hence $\sum_j \alpha(v_j)-\alpha(u_j) = \sum_{i \in B} \Delta \alpha_i \lt \epsilon$. This complete the proof.

Comment: In proof of (1)(2), you could have use better notation. Anyway that is not a huge problem for me.